# asp button and history back onclientclick

Tags: javascript, asp.net, clientscript

hi I have an asp button  which is created using the following code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBack" OnClientClick='javascript:history.back()' runat="server" Text="back">
</asp:Button>
```

However, now the javascript doesn't work to go a history back. On the other hand, if I make an alert() it works...why. Why is it not working to go a history back?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try with **return false** at end:

```
 <asp:button id="btnBack" runat="server" text="Back" 
OnClientClick="JavaScript: window.history.back(1); return false;"></asp:button>
```

Comment: asp:button will do a postback, so return false on your javascript prevents that postback

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
parent.history.back();
```

Or

```
history.go(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in DevExpress project. Using ASPxButton without initializing the property "AutoPostBack" will result in redirect to self page before any client-side function call.
Try `AutoPostBack="false"` for the button.